# Styling scrollbar to overlay to border right

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a problem styling a scrollbar like this. Is it possible to style it this way?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can design with these selectors but not recommended.

```
::webkit-scrollbar  
::webkit-scrollbar-thumb  
::webkit-scrollbar-track
```

i think it is better to hide scrollbar and create fake scrollbar which moves by javascript code.
you can hide it with display: none attribute

Comment: thanks so much for your advice. I'll try to do this with javascript  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1; 
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #555; 
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #333; 
}
```

It's not possible to decrease the width of scrollbar track, rest is possible. Also, do note that you cannot change scrollbar styles for Firefox and older versions of Edge.

Comment: Thanks for your response is there a way to overlap the scrollbar to the border right of the div?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to style your scroll bar.

For chrome browser, you can use these snippets:

```
::webkit-scrollbar  
::webkit-scrollbar-thumb  
::webkit-scrollbar-track
```

To apply your style for all browsers, you can use these JS libraries:

[Overlay Scrollbars](https://kingsora.github.io/OverlayScrollbars/#!overview) or [Simple Bar](https://grsmto.github.io/simplebar/)